# Pass an integer to a function running in a gcnew task vc++ .net

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to pass an incremental integer to a function which is going to run in a different task in .NET C++.

```
Public: void loop()
          { 
           int i=0;max=100;
           while(i<max){
                Task ^newtask= gcnew Task (gcnew Action(&mainform::dosomething),cancellationtoken);
                i++;
                }
           }
Public: Void dosomething(int j)
        {

        }
```

Here I want to pass the integer `i` to the function `dosomething` which is going to be method for the new task.

Please help me to solve this issue of passing the argument to a task in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the version of the `Task` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783035%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `Action<Object>` parameter so you can pass the required input arguments, including the cancellation token, to the method executed by the task.

Example:

```
ref class Test
{
public:
    void Loop()
    { 
        auto tokenSource = gcnew CancellationTokenSource();
        auto token = tokenSource->Token;

           int i = 0, max = 100;
           while (i < max)
           {
               auto tuple = gcnew tuple_t(i, token);
               auto newtask = gcnew Task(gcnew Action<Object^>(this, &Test::DoSomething), tuple, token);
               newtask->Start();
               i++;
           }
    }

    void DoSomething(Object^ state)
    {
        auto tuple = static_cast<tuple_t^>(state);
        int data = tuple->Item1;
        CancellationToken token = tuple->Item2;
        // ...
    }

private:
    typedef Tuple<int, CancellationToken> tuple_t;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sebacote. You helped me to solve the issue. I could pass the integer as an argument to the tasks.